# textView not refreshing in fragment with updated text (Android Development)

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, android-tabs

In my Android project, I have a class that extends FragmentActivity in order to display 2 tabs (which are fragments). I am trying to pass data from a JSON Object in one Activity to a textView on one of these tabs. I followed this tutorial to create the tabs: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/
The JSON Object is being successfully passed to the appropriate FragmentActivity, and the textView is successfully being set. However, it will not display on the tab.

Since I have the tabs set up in another package, I used a LayoutInflater to access the descriptionText TextView field in the infoFrag.xml file. I can see the text being set through my Toast box, but the fragment being displayed on the screen isn't actually getting updated.

Does anyone have insight to the problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EventInfo.java**

```
public class EventInfo extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

JSONObject obj;
GoogleMap map;
double latitude, longitude = 0;
String address = "";
String titleEvent = "";

private TextView descriptionText;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

// tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Event Info", "Google Map" };

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.eventinfo);

// Initialization:
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// Adding Tabs
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
    .setTabListener(this));
}

try {
    obj = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("json"));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "event = " + obj.getString("summary"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
    address = obj.getString("location");
    titleEvent = obj.getString("summary");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//I think the problem is somewhere in this code block!
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View descripText = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_infofrag, null);
descriptionText = (TextView) descripText.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
descriptionText.setText("updated text"); //the textView gets updated here!
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "display: "+ descriptionText.getText(),     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Toast box correctly displays, but the textView on the actual tab does not
}
```

**TabsPagerAdapter.java**

```
package com.uva.tabswipe.adapter;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.uva.tabswipe.adapter.InfoFragment;
import com.uva.tabswipe.adapter.GMapFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }    

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Tab with event info
            return new InfoFragment();
        case 1:
            // Tab with Google Map Fragment (this one is working fine)
            return new GMapFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }

}
```

**InfoFragment.java**

```
package com.uva.tabswipe.adapter;...

public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView descriptionText;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_infofrag, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**fragment_infofrag.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0EEEE"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#F88017"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please put TabsPagerAdapter code. You don't see text in TextView because when execute descripText = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_infofrag, null); was created new view that dont attach to your layout.

Comment: @fisher3421 I added TabsPagerAdapter as well as the corresponding fragment class and xml layout if that helps. How would I attach the descripText to my fragment layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from another fragment, and trying to update text in onActivityResult, then the below text would work

```
      final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 500ms
                message.setText("Saved");
            }
        }, 500);
```